# Find method not assigning values to object

Tags: c#, linq

I have a web project that everything is working and this below line works for other models except for this one. I'm just needing some info on where to start looking for the solution at.

When I debug it I see that it is getting all the new data that has been edited but it does not assign the new data to EditedtimeEntry. The EditedtimeEntry var has the old data not the new data that was edited. I looked at the timeEntry.Id and it has the new edit its just not being assigned to the EditedtimeEntry. There is no exception or build errors it just does not save the changes, and it looks like the reason it is not save the changes is because the EditedtimeEntry var is not getting the new data assigned to it for some reason. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
TimeEntry EditedtimeEntry = db.TimeEntries.Find(timeEntry.Id);
```

Here is the Full method with the problem:

```
public ActionResult Edit( [Bind(Include = "Id,Description,Rate,Paid,Tech,Company")] TimeEntry timeEntry)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        TimeEntry EditedtimeEntry = db.TimeEntries.Find(timeEntry.Id);
        Technician tech = db.Technician.Single(m => m.PhoneNumber == timeEntry.Tech.PhoneNumber);
        EditedtimeEntry.Tech = tech;
        Company comp = db.Companies.Single(m => m.Name == timeEntry.Company.Name);
        EditedtimeEntry.Company = comp;
        db.Entry(EditedtimeEntry).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(timeEntry);
}
```

I have other methods for other models that are identical to this one and it works. Here is alsos the model

```
public class TimeEntry
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Rate Rate { get; set; }
    public Technician Tech { get; set; }
    public bool Paid { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }

}

public enum Rate { Desktop, Network, Remote, Phone }
```

Thanks =)

Comment: can you include a working example rather than just the line that fails?

Comment: here is the method that is having the trouble:

Comment: If you are editing the entry in a separate line of code, then have you used db.SaveChanges() in-between? It seems you simply didn't update the information in database

Comment: Pretty sure c# will assign the whole object, not just parts of it. Perhaps the data is coming back wrong. Have you looked into the database to see if the data are correct?

Comment: No, the issue is slightly more than what we see here. Why do you have a parameter that's the entity with your edits but not simply attach it? You don't need to set the state to modified if your DbContext has change taking enabled... There's just so much that's not quite right here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, what you are doing is exactly the contrary of what you want to do :) when you recover the item from the database, you are simply getting the item unchanged that is still in database. What you want is update the database item and then save changes (with EntityState.Modified then SaveChanges())

You simply want to edit timeEntry so that all changes done in the UI are translated into DB :

```
public ActionResult Edit( [Bind(Include = "Id,Description,Rate,Paid,Tech,Company")] TimeEntry timeEntry)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Technician tech = db.Technician.Single(m => m.PhoneNumber == timeEntry.Tech.PhoneNumber);
            timeEntry.Tech = tech;
            Company comp = db.Companies.Single(m => m.Name == timeEntry.Company.Name);
            timeEntry.Company = comp;
            db.Entry(timeEntry).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(timeEntry);
    }
```